# Overriding toString() for one particular instance of a Multimap?

Tags: java, hashmap, tostring

I have an instance of a ListMultimap (Guava) which is composed of nested HashMaps and rather complex objects -- is there any way to change the toString() for this instance to customize the console output when I print the HashMap? Or is the only way to make a new class which is an extension of the HashMap class, and rewrite the toString() method as follows:

```
class CustomizedListMultiMap extends ListMultiMap<myComplexDatatypeOne, myComplexDatatypeTwo> {
    // overwriting toString
    public String toString() {
        // my custom implementation
    }
}
```

Multimaps are instantiated as follows:

```
ListMultimap<datatypeOne, datatypeTwo> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

so I don't think the first answer is applicable? (Thanks though.)

Comment: What customization are you trying to do that you can't do on the `toString` of the element types, instead of the collection type?

Comment: Hmmm, the values of the ListMultimap are lists themselves; I want to be able to grab the length of these values.

Comment: Wait, clarification: do you have a `ListMultimap<Foo, Bar>`, or a `ListMultimap<Foo, List<Bar>>`?  If the former, then just `multimap.keys().toString()` would probably do what you need.

Comment: The latter! Could you put up your previous comment? Haha. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm under the impression you have a `ListMultimap<Foo, List<Bar>>`, and you want to print it out in a format looking like `{a=[1, 2, 3]}` corresponding to the lengths of the `List<Bar>`s.

The simplest way to do that is probably

```
Multimaps.transformValues(multimap, new Function<List<Bar>, Integer>() {
   public Integer apply(List<Bar> list) {
     return list.size();
   }
}).toString();
```

Answer (score 4):

How about an anonymous class:

```
Map<X, Y> map = new HashMap<X, Y>() {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // toString implementation here
    }
};
```

---

**EDIT:** Looks like you want to do this with a `final` class. I would instead suggest writing a separate `static toString` method and calling that instead, instead of somehow trying to add it to the class itself:

```
public static String mapToString(Map<X, Y> map) {
    // toString implementation here
}
```

Comment: Oh wait, thanks for the response, but I realized the type of my Map is actually a Multimap, from the Guava library. Editing OP right now, I apologize!

Comment: @RyanYu You should be able to apply the same idea.

Comment: @arshajii: No, you shouldn't; the `Multimap` implementations are `final`.

Comment: Hmmmm, the item is instantiated with a create() method, not a proper constructor though?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Oh, I was unaware. I added another suggestion.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Ended up implementing it both ways.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the toString() method in your custom class "customizedHashMap". You can not customize the toString() method only for one instance of your class.

I suggest you use class names with the first letter capitalized!